# how to do normalization for training data where each example has two dimensional information

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I would like to do normalization ((x - mean)/standard_deviation) before training. My training data are saved in several files, and each file is too large and cannot fit into memory. For every training example, it has two dimensional features. It seems all tutorials are about how to normalize with one dimensional features. How to do normalization for my case? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about? Your question is very broad and I am afraid it is impossible to answer it this way. Please add more details.

Comment: Thank you. My data are numerical values, and the files for training data are tab-delimited. For every training example, it has features of 2805 rows and 222 columns (the 222th column is for label).